# How to get specific changeset version treated as changes relative to latest version?

Tags: tfs, shelveset, tfvc

I rolled back a changeset. Now I need to check out the changeset that was rolled back with 'actualized' pending changes. So like everything is before the commit of the changes.

When I get specific version with files override I see nothing in pending changes window.
How can I get the state I need? Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After doing the "Get Specific version" you need to check out every file in the changeset manually (right-click, check-out). Be sure that you have the "Get latest on checkout" turned off.

After that perform a get latest, which will prompt you to merge. This is going to be a more tricky merge, since Visual Studio will assume that the newer version is what you want. When you're satisfied, check in the code.

Alternatively start with the same steps as the first solution, but instead of immediately doing a get-latest, you can create a shelfset after you've checked out each file and then perform a get latest. When you're on the target version, unshelf your changes, resolve any conflicts and check them back in.

Another trick you could apply is to find the changeset number that contains the rolled back changes. Since this checkin is a compensating checkin, you might also be able to re-do the changes by rolling back that compensating changeset. I tried this in a local workspace and it works. Again  you might need to go through a merge and it's hard to tell exactly which changes to pick.

My best advice on this is: try not to get into this situation :).

Comment: Checking out each file for edit also works when you "Get This Version" on the changeset. This is MUCH quicker than "Get Specific version" because you don't have to download the whole repo again.